# OSGI classloader DTMManager

Tags: java, osgi, classloader, eclipse-virgo

I am converting an existing application over to OSGI and have ran in to the following issue:

```
[2015-04-24 15:13:07.575] DEBUG start-signalling-3           o.e.gemini.web.tomcat.internal.loading.BundleWebappClassLoader    getResource(META-INF/services/com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.dtm.DTMManager) 
[2015-04-24 15:13:07.637] DEBUG start-signalling-3           o.e.gemini.web.tomcat.internal.loading.BundleWebappClassLoader      --> Resource not found, returning null 
[2015-04-24 15:13:07.637] DEBUG start-signalling-3           o.e.gemini.web.tomcat.internal.loading.BundleWebappClassLoader    loadClass(com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.dtm.ref.DTMManagerDefault, false) 
[2015-04-24 15:13:07.637] DEBUG start-signalling-3           o.e.gemini.web.tomcat.internal.loading.BundleWebappClassLoader      Searching the application's bundle 
[2015-04-24 15:13:07.637] DEBUG start-signalling-3           o.e.gemini.web.tomcat.internal.loading.BundleWebappClassLoader      Loading class from the delegating classloader 
[2015-04-24 15:13:07.637] DEBUG start-signalling-3           o.e.gemini.web.tomcat.internal.loading.BundleWebappClassLoader    getResource(META-INF/services/com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.dtm.DTMManager) 
[2015-04-24 15:13:07.684] DEBUG start-signalling-3           o.e.gemini.web.tomcat.internal.loading.BundleWebappClassLoader      --> Resource not found, returning null 
[2015-04-24 15:13:07.684] DEBUG start-signalling-3           o.e.gemini.web.tomcat.internal.loading.BundleWebappClassLoader    loadClass(com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.dtm.ref.DTMManagerDefault, false) 
[2015-04-24 15:13:07.684] DEBUG start-signalling-3           o.e.gemini.web.tomcat.internal.loading.BundleWebappClassLoader      Searching the application's bundle 
[2015-04-24 15:13:07.684] DEBUG start-signalling-3           o.e.gemini.web.tomcat.internal.loading.BundleWebappClassLoader      Loading class from the delegating classloader 
[2015-04-24 15:13:07.684] DEBUG start-signalling-3           o.e.gemini.web.tomcat.internal.loading.BundleWebappClassLoader    getResource(META-INF/services/com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.dtm.DTMManager) 
[2015-04-24 15:13:07.746] DEBUG start-signalling-3           o.e.gemini.web.tomcat.internal.loading.BundleWebappClassLoader      --> Resource not found, returning null 
[2015-04-24 15:13:07.746] DEBUG start-signalling-3           o.e.gemini.web.tomcat.internal.loading.BundleWebappClassLoader    loadClass(com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.dtm.ref.DTMManagerDefault, false) 
[2015-04-24 15:13:07.746] DEBUG start-signalling-3           o.e.gemini.web.tomcat.internal.loading.BundleWebappClassLoader      Searching the application's bundle 
[2015-04-24 15:13:07.746] DEBUG start-signalling-3           o.e.gemini.web.tomcat.internal.loading.BundleWebappClassLoader      Loading class from the delegating classloader 
[2015-04-24 15:13:07.746] DEBUG start-signalling-3           o.e.gemini.web.tomcat.internal.loading.BundleWebappClassLoader    getResource(META-INF/services/com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.dtm.DTMManager) 
[2015-04-24 15:13:07.780] DEBUG start-signalling-3           o.e.gemini.web.tomcat.internal.loading.BundleWebappClassLoader      --> Resource not found, returning null 
[2015-04-24 15:13:07.781] DEBUG start-signalling-3           o.e.gemini.web.tomcat.internal.loading.BundleWebappClassLoader    loadClass(com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.dtm.ref.DTMManagerDefault, false)
```

As you can see, it is continually trying to load the DTMManager over and over again.  I have made it through the rest of the errors in my logs and this is the final thing that I see.  I have tried many things to get this to load and from what I have read it should be loaded by the parent class loader from the bootloader as per the config file.  I see the entry for org.osgi.framework.bootdelegation and it does include those packages:

```
org.osgi.framework.bootdelegation = \
 org.eclipse.virgo.osgi.extensions.*,\
 org.eclipse.virgo.osgi.launcher.*,\
 org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.authentication,\
 com.sun.*,\
 javax.xml.*,\
 org.apache.xerces.jaxp.*,\
 org.w3c.*,\
 org.xml.*,\
 sun.*
```

Any help would be awesome!

Thanks

Comment: In which stage of the conversion does this error happen? Are you deploying the unmodified WAR file or already a modular OSGi web application bundle (WAB)?

Comment: Deploying a partially converted WAR(that virgo converts to a wab at runtime due to manifest headers). I am using the maven bundler to get my dependencies specified as embedded artifacts(still in the lib directory).

Comment: I assume you added the Bundle-Classpath header like Bundle-Classpath: foo.jar,bar.jar,WEB-INF/classes ?